# more concise way to make this?

Tags: python, list

I'm unsure of how to create a certain section of my code without it being excessively long and tedious. Is there perhaps a way of utilizing a range function where I need my elif statements? Any help shortening this would be more than appreciated!

```
#just some sample lists
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row = [0,1,2,3,4]
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col = [5,5,5,5,5]

Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row = [10,11,12,13]
Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col = [15,15,15,15]

if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row[0] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col[0] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row[1] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col[1] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row[2] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col[2] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row[3] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col[3] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row[4] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col[4] == row:
        print('hit')

elif Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row[0] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col[0] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row[1] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col[1] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row[2] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col[2] == row:
        print('hit')
elif Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row[3] == column:
    if Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col[3] == row:
        print('hit')

else:
print('miss')
```

Comment: Yes there is, but it's not hard to figure out, just look at where the numbers are incrementing and put it in a loop.

Comment: yes, a range function will work. you can change `battleship_row[0]` (and all the following indexes) for `battleship_row[i]`

Comment: In your own words, what is the *pattern* behind all of these `if`s and `elif`s? "Is there perhaps a way of utilizing a range function where I need my elif statements?" Yes, there is. If you aren't familiar with it, you should review whatever tutorial, textbook or other notes you have been using to learn Python. Stack Overflow isn't meant to teach the fundamentals; you should have them properly studied before trying to work on your own projects.

Comment: [Zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the 2 lists together and loop over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I think the data format is inappropriate. If you have the ability to change it, I would suggest redesigning your data model to deal with points instead of individual point coordinates `(x, y)`, e.g.:

```py
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier = [(0, 5), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4,5)]
```

Then your check on a hit can be as simple as:

```
def is_hit(row: int, column: int) -> bool:
    point = (row, column)
    return (point in Player.PlayerList[1].carrier 
            or point in Player.PlayerList[1].battleship)
```

EDIT: Assuming you're trying to build a battleship game, I would probably write a class `Ship` which manages one ship, and then use multiple of these, so something like:

```py
class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int

class Ship(object):
    def __init__(self, points: List[Point]):
        self.points = points

    def check_hit(self, point: Point) -> bool:
        return point in self.points
```

The benefit of that is that you can now start adding logic to the `Ship` easily, for example by adding a `.hits` attribute as well that allows you to keep track of the ship health.

A player could then simply have a list of ships:

```py
Player.PlayerList[1].ships = [
    Ship([Point(0, 5), Point(1, 5), Point(2, 5), Point(3, 5), Point(4,5)],
    Ship(...),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a loop to look all the possibility without having to write them all:

```py
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row = [0,1,2,3,4]
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col = [5,5,5,5,5]

Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row = [10,11,12,13]
Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col = [15,15,15,15]

hit = False 

for i in range(len(Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row)):
    if Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row[i] == row and Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col == column:
        print("hit")
        hit = True

for i in range(len(Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row)):
    if Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row[i] == row and Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col == column:
        print("hit")
        hit = True

if not hit:
    print("miss")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more concise but untested as the values for *row* and *column* and the class definitions are unknown :

```
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row = [0,1,2,3,4]
Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_col = [5,5,5,5,5]

Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row = [10,11,12,13]
Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_col = [15,15,15,15]

pli = Player.PlayerList[1]

for cr, cc, br, bc in zip(pli.carrier_row, pli.carrier_col, pli.battleship_row, pli.battleship_col):
    if row in (cr, br) or column in (cc, bc):
        hit = True
        break
else:
    hit = False

print('hit' if hit else 'miss')
```

Answer (score 0):

Each check is done against a fix value, `column` & `row`, so one can compare them individually and them `zip` them. The nested condition is performed with an `and`. Used [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to keep the code compact

```
import itertools as it

column = # some number
row = #    some number


cc_cols = map(column.__eq__, Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row)
cc_rows = map(row.__eq__, Player.PlayerList[1].carrier_row)

bship_cols = map(column.__eq__, Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row)
bship_rows = map(row.__eq__, Player.PlayerList[1].battleship_row)

if any(it.starmap(bool.__and__, it.chain(zip(cc_cols, cc_rows), zip(bship_cols, bship_rows)))):
    print('hit')
else:
    print('miss')
```